# Displaying dynamic text based on drop down box selection

Tags: php, dynamic, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I am using Dreamweaver to create a site.
I have created my database within phpMyAdmin and have two tables set up that contain the data I wish to display on my site. (it is a football team site and the page I am editing displays player profiles).

I have set up a drop down box, which is connected to my players table in phpMyAdmin. This I have set to display surname of the player. (I've set up the recordset to retrieve all data from my "players" table)
Below that, I have another div which contains text that I want to display based on the selection on the drop down list. For example, Position, appearances, goals, assists, etc.

Position: **Dynamic text to be displayed here**
Appearances: **Dynamic text to be displayed here**
etc
(This data would come from the "players_info" table - but the two tables are connected via the player_id field which is contained in both)

What I can't seem to do is work out how to get the text to update when the user would select a player from the drop down list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 0):

You can do these using ajax function.
when you select a player name ,then javascript or jquery event will be called which include a php file.
This php file must contain the sql which fetch your desired player information.
when server give response, then display it your corresponding div

Comment: Thanks for this. Trying to work my way though adding an ajax example I have found and editing the code. Hopefully, will work.

Comment: Just to let you know, got this to work using the ajax function. Thanks alot for your help!